# Maven is not working in Java 8 when Javadoc tags are incomplete

Tags: java, maven, migration, java-8, javadoc

Since I use Maven I have been able to build and install in my local repository projects that have incomplete Javadoc tags (for example, a missing parameter).

However, since I migrated to Java 8 (1.8.0-ea-b90) Maven is absolutely strict about missing documentation tags and show me lots of Javadoc errors related to Javadoc problems when I try to build or install a project where the Javadoc is not "perfect". Some of the projects I am trying to compile and install in my local repository are third party projects from which I do not have control. So the workaround of just fixing all the Javadocs in all these projects does not seem to be feasable in my scenario.

This is a small part of the output I see when I execute `mvn clean package install` in my project:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.026s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Apr 08 21:06:17 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/437M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.9:jar (attach-javadocs) on project jpc: MavenReportException: Error while creating archive:
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - /Users/sergioc/Documents/workspaces/heal/jpc/src/main/java/org/jpc/engine/prolog/PrologDatabase.java:10: error: @param name not found
[ERROR] * @param terms the terms to assert
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /Users/sergioc/Documents/workspaces/heal/jpc/src/main/java/org/jpc/engine/prolog/PrologDatabase.java:11: warning: no description for @return
[ERROR] * @return
[ERROR] ^
```

The Javadoc Maven plugin is configured like this in my POM:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

As I said before, everything is working fine if I go back to Java 7. 
Maybe is this a bug related to Maven running in Java 8?
How could I make it work (i.e., being able to build the Javadoc of the project and install its code in my local repository) with Java 8?
I have tested with both Maven 3.0.3 and 3.0.5 in OSX.

**UPDATE:**

If I change my Javadoc plugin configuration with `<failOnError>false</failOnError>` (thanks Martin):

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then the project is installed in my local repository. However, the Javadoc JAR is still not generated.

A fragment of the output I see in the console with this new configuration is:

> [ERROR] MavenReportException: Error while creating archive:  Exit
>   code: 1 - /Users/....java:18: warning: no @param  ... Command line
>   was: /Library/Java/Home/bin/javadoc @options @packages
>
> Refer to the generated Javadoc files in
>   '/Users/sergioc/Documents/workspaces/heal/minitoolbox/target/apidocs'
>   dir.
>
> at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.executeJavadocCommandLine(AbstractJavadocMojo.java:5043)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.executeReport(AbstractJavadocMojo.java:1990)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.JavadocJar.execute(JavadocJar.java:181)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)

Any workaround about how to build the sources, install the project and generate the Javadoc JAR in one step as it was working with Java 7?

Comment: Hi @75inchpianist, I have updated the question, in fact they are errors (although surprisingly enough the last line of the error refers to a warning, as you can see in the generated output). The project is not installed in my local repository, so it is not considered as a simple warning :(

Comment: For GoogleJuice: I got the error "error: bad use of '>'" because I had a big arrow in JavaDoc comment

Comment: Maybe it will be useful for someone: You can easily find all this incomplete tags in IntelliJ by running inspection Ctrl+Alt+Shift+i  "Declaration has JavaDoc problems"

Comment: This is not maven, it is the javadoc program which got a lot stricter in Java 8.

Answer (score 425, accepted):

The best solution would be to fix the javadoc errors. If for some reason that is not possible (ie: auto generated source code) then you can disable this check.

[DocLint is a new feature in Java 8](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/172), which is summarized as:

> Provide a means to detect errors in Javadoc comments early in the
>   development cycle and in a way that is easily linked back to the
>   source code.

This is enabled by default, and will run a whole lot of checks before generating Javadocs. You need to turn this off for Java 8 as specified [in this thread](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/build-infra-dev/2013-January/002899.html). You'll have to add this to your maven configuration:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>java8-doclint-disabled</id>
    <activation>
      <jdk>[1.8,)</jdk>
    </activation>
    <properties>
      <javadoc.opts>-Xdoclint:none</javadoc.opts>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalparam>${javadoc.opts}</additionalparam>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <reportPlugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                <additionalparam>${javadoc.opts}</additionalparam>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

**For maven-javadoc-plugin 3.0.0+:**
Replace

```
<additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
```

with

```
<doclint>none</doclint>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with JDK 8 _as well as_ JDK 7? It fails on JDK 7 because its `javadoc` doesn't know this option.

Comment: BTW, Xdoclint parameter can be configured more flexible. E.g. to disable annoying HTML checks just use `-Xdoclint:-html`

Comment: This doesn't work for me unfortunately (Java 1.8, maven 3.0.5) Any ideas why?

Comment: While this answers the question asked here, I'd like to advise future visitors to check peterh's answer first: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34809831/1180785 (most people hitting this issue will only have a handful of places to fix, so it's better to fix them than disable the check!)

Comment: This does not work with maven-javadoc-plugin version 3.0.0. I had to go back to version 3.0.0-M1 for making -Xdoclint:none work.

Comment: For maven-javadoc-plugin, use `<doclint>none</doclint>`. See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#doclint

Comment: Also since maven-javadoc-plugin 3.0.0, `<additionalparam/>` is replaced by `<additionalOptions/>`. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAVADOC-475

Comment: By "configuration", what do you mean excatly? *Really* helps to be specific about steps to apply fixes. Please don't assume some noob or someone focused on a different layer knows much about some sub-invocation and how it's configured.  To save time, could someone mention anything about how to quickly locate the maven configuration on macOS, Linux ...? On Debian Linux running `dpkg -L maven` implies `/etc/maven/settings`. And running: `find . -name "*plugin*"` in `/usr/share/maven` (also listed in `dpkg -L output`) shows. `./lib/maven-plugin-api-3.x.jar`

Answer (score 102):

The easiest approach to get things working with both java 8 and java 7 is to use a profile in the build:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>doclint-java8-disable</id>
    <activation>
      <jdk>[1.8,)</jdk>
    </activation>

    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: The best solution would probably be a Hybrid between your solution and the one Zapp provided bellow.

If you leave it this way, the mvn site:site command will still be crashing.
You should create a profile activated by the 1.8 jdk that sets a global property.

Answer (score 66):

Here is the most concise way I am aware of to ignore doclint warnings regardless of java version used. There is no need to duplicate plugin configuration in multiple profiles with slight modifications.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>doclint-java8-disable</id>
    <activation>
      <jdk>[1.8,)</jdk>
    </activation>
    <properties>
      <javadoc.opts>-Xdoclint:none</javadoc.opts>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.1</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>attach-javadocs</id> <!-- The actual id should be apparent from maven output -->
          <configuration>
            <additionalparam>${javadoc.opts}</additionalparam>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Tested on oracle/open jdk 6, 7, 8 and 11.

Comment: @clearlight, both `build` and `profiles` are top-level blocks in maven `pom.xml`. https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Build.

Answer (score 45):

## The shortest solution that will work with any Java version:

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>disable-java8-doclint</id>
        <activation>
            <jdk>[1.8,)</jdk>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Just add that to your POM and you're good to go.

This is basically [@ankon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22296107/2352699) plus [@zapp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30274114/2352699).

---

#### For maven-javadoc-plugin 3.0.0 users:

Replace

`<additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>`

by

`<doclint>none</doclint>`

Comment: It is the best solution for me. It works for bots java 7 and java 8. But the way it work is a kind of magic :. How does this parameter "additionalParam" add to  the plugin javadoc (and not to the others)

Comment: @pdem The additional parameter is added to Maven, not to the Javadoc plugin. This solution works whether you're explicitly using the plugin or not.

Comment: Since maven-javadoc-plugin 3.0.0, you have to add`<additionalJOption>-Xdoclint:none</additionalJOption>` or `<doclint>none</doclint>` property to your `<properties>`

Comment: Can you clarify: with maven-javadoc-plugin 3.0.0 and above, if I simply specify `<doclint>none</doclint>` (with no JDK version-based activation), will it still fail on JDK less than 1.8, or does maven-javadoc-plugin automatically detect whether the `doclint` option is supported by the current version of Java?

Answer (score 38):

Add into the global properties section in the pom file:

```
<project>
    ...
    <properties>
        <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
    </properties>
```

The common solution provided here in the other answers (adding that property in the plugins section) did not work for some reason. Only by setting it globally I could build the javadoc jar successfully.

Comment: this is the only solution that worked for me. I read the answer here as well: http://blog.joda.org/2014/02/turning-off-doclint-in-jdk-8-javadoc.html

Answer (score 34):

I don't think just turning off DocLint is a good solution, at least not long term. It is good that Javadoc has become a bit more strict so the right way to fix the build problem is to **fix the underlying problem**. Yes, you'll ultimately need to fix those source code files.

Here are the things to look out for that you could previously get away with:

- Malformed HTML (for example a missing end-tag, un-escaped brackets, etc)
- Invalid `{@link }`s. (same goes for similar tags such as `@see`)
- Invalid `@author` values. This used to be accepted : `@author John <john.doe@mine.com>` but not so anymore because of the un-escaped brackets.
- HTML tables in Javadoc now require a summary or caption. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22528767/1504556) for explanation.

You'll simply have to fix your source code files and keep building your Javadoc until it can build without a failure. Cumbersome yes, but personally I like when I have brought my projects up to DocLint level because it means I can be more confident that the Javadoc I produce is actually what I intend.

There's of course the problem if you are generating Javadoc on some source code you've not produced yourself, for example because it comes from some code generator, e.g. [wsimport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/index.html#webservices). Strange that Oracle didn't prepare their own tools for JDK8 compliance before actually releasing JDK8. It seems [it won't be fixed until Java 9](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/212). Only in this particular case I suggest to turn off DocLint as documented elsewhere on this page.

Comment: Completely agree here, that said, for generated code you can simply tell the plugin to not process code in a given package by adding a excludePackageNames section in the javadoc plugin`s configuration section.  see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/exclude-package-names.html

Comment: That's SO much easier said than done since a lot of us running into these problems are trying to build unfamiliar opensource code that has a Maven dependency somewhere and we have no idea how it all works, so have no easy way to address the underlying causes. There's too much myopia about the context. People need to generalize the scope of the answers more and provide more specifics about how to make the fixes.

Comment: "javadoc: error - Error decoding percent encoded characters" I haven't found any way to fix the javadoc (doesn't help that there is no indication where the problem lies within a small/simple internal library (I don't know if it's a maven dependency or not)) - mvn javadoc:fix made a bunch of additions to my files but did not fix the underlying issue. I'm going to have to disable doclint to get mvn release:perform to work

Comment: I used mvn clean -Darguments="-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true" release:perform

Answer (score 31):

Overriding `maven-javadoc-plugin` configuration only, does not fix the problem with `mvn site` (used e.g during the release stage). Here's what I had to do:

```
<profile>
  <id>doclint-java8-disable</id>
  <activation>
    <jdk>[1.8,)</jdk>
  </activation>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <reportPlugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

Comment: This is an important point as the lack of this setting in the site-plugin activation will cause release:perform to fail while release:prepare has worked fine. It can be a very annoying problem to find and fix.

Comment: Note, that the configuration of the `maven-javadoc-plugin` via the `<reportPlugins>` section of the `maven-site-plugin` is [not recommended](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/maven-3.html#Configuration_formats) for recent versions of Maven 3.

Comment: I used mvn clean -Darguments="-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true" release:perform

Answer (score 28):

You could try setting the `failOnError` property (see [plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#failOnError)) to `false`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <failOnError>false</failOnError>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

As you can see from the docs, the default value is `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea @Martin. With that property at least I can build and install the project again, however I am still missing the java doc jar (I need it to deploy to Maven central). I updated my question with the details of the experiment.

Comment: This was the most sufficient answer for me. I just wanted to test building during ongoing development when javadocs were still incomplete.

Answer (score 18):

Since it depends on the version of your JRE which is used to run the maven command you propably dont want to disable `DocLint` per default in your pom.xml

Hence, from command line you can use the switch `-Dadditionalparam=-Xdoclint:none`.

Example: `mvn clean install -Dadditionalparam=-Xdoclint:none`

Comment: This is particularly useful because you can use it Jenkins too. Set 'Global MAVEN_OPTS' (under 'Configure System') to `-Dadditionalparam=-Xdoclint:none` and all your builds will work with Java 8.

Comment: `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.1.0:jar -DadditionalJOption=-Xdoclint:none` - it worked for me

Answer (score 11):

The configuration property name has been changed in the latest version of maven-javadoc-plugin which is 3.0.0.

Hence the <additionalparam> will not work. So we have to modify it as below.

```
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <configuration>
         <doclint>none</doclint>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: See `doclint` documentation here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#doclint

Comment: Resolved it for me building OpenGrok from github source in Feb'19. Should mention your patch goes into `pom.xml` in project's src/build directory. In my case all I had to do was search for `maven-javadoc-plugin` and then go to the `<configuration></configuration>` block already present and add `<doclint>none</doclint>`. As easy as all of this is once one knows, the context here is I'm trying to fix a different bug in OpenGrok and have never used Maven before and don't want to have to recurse into another sub project just to have to figure out how to apply quick fixes.

Answer (score 5):

As of maven-javadoc-plugin 3.0.0 you should have been using [additionalJOption](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#additionalJOption) to set an additional Javadoc option, so if you would like Javadoc to disable doclint, you should add the following property.

```
<properties>
    ...
    <additionalJOption>-Xdoclint:none</additionalJOption>
    ...
<properties>
```

You should also mention the version of maven-javadoc-plugin as 3.0.0 or higher.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>    
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add some insight into other answers

In my case

> -Xdoclint:none

Didn't work.

Let start with that, in my project, I didn't really need javadoc at all. Only some necessary plugins had got a build time dependency on it.

So, the most simple way solve my problem was:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

Added below

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-DadditionalJOption=-Xdoclint:none
```

Into Jenkins job :

***Configuration > Build Environment > Inject environment variables to the build process > Properties Content***

Solved my problem of code building through Jenkins Maven :-)

Comment: This works for maven-javadoc-plugin 2.4 but starting in 2.5 (and all the way through 3.0.0), this causes an error: "Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - invalid flag: -Xdoclint:none".  So the solution is brittle.

Comment: When using this with ```mvn release:perform``` the syntax needs to be ```mvn release:perform -Darguments="-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true"```.

Answer (score 3):

So, save yourself some hours that I didn't and try this if it seems not to work:

```
 <additionalJOption>-Xdoclint:none</additionalJOption>
```

The tag is changed for newer versions.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#additionalJOption

Comment: Sometimes `-Xdoclint` itself is not enough, but additional args are needed. Newer versions of the `maven-javadoc-plugin` provide `additionalJOptions` for that, older don't. A workaround is: `<additionalJOption>"-Xdoclint:none" "--allow-script-in-comments"</additionalJOption>` Quotes are important, else the plugin adds them and assumes only one arg instead of two, resulting in `wrong args` errors.

Comment: The former works on Windows only, on Linux instead: `javadoc: error - Illegal package name: ""-Xdoclint:none" "--allow-script-in-comments""` The outer quotes are added by the logging statement and not present on the shell. I guess the problem is that on Windows `javadoc` is executed by `cmd.exe`, which parses one large string as command line and splits the `additionalJOption`as intended. On Linux the args are passed individually to the process directly and `additionalJOption` gets passed as one argument, leading to the error.

Comment: According to `Process Monitor`, `cmd.exe` is not used. Java most likely simply builds one large command line and passes that to `CreateProcess`, so that it gets  parsed by Windows as intended: Splitting args at spaces while honouring quotes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is going to help, but even i faced the exact same problem very recently with **oozie-4.2.0** version.  After reading through the above answers i have just added the maven option through command line and it worked for me.  So, just sharing here.

I'm using java **1.8.0_77**, haven't tried with java 1.7

bin/mkdistro.sh -DskipTests **-Dmaven.javadoc.opts='-Xdoclint:-html'**

Answer (score 1):

To ignore missing `@param` and `@return` tags, it's enough to disable the `missing` [doclint group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#BEJEFABE). This way, the javadoc will still be checked for higher level and syntax issues:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <doclint>all,-missing</doclint>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Note that this is for plugin version 3.0 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party, but I was forced to search for workaround too, ended up here, and then found it.

Here's what works for me:-

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-DadditionalJOption=-Xdoclint:none
```

And then start your Maven build, any Linux distribution build etc. Nice thing about it that it doesn't require Maven *config* files modification - I couldn't do that as my objective was to rebuild a bunch of **Centos** rpm packages, so had to go really deep.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using a parent pom (not sure it was the real cause since I was running against the clock), maven 2.x and java 1.6 were used, for some reason above solutions didn't work, so I added the following profile and managed it to make it run:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>myapp</name>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <description>My App</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>doclint-java6-disable</id>
            <activation>
                <jdk>[1.6,)</jdk>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <additionalparam>--allow-script-in-comments</additionalparam>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Update: according to this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6871, it should work in Java version lower than JDK 8 update release 1.8.0_u121, otherwise it would complain you passed an unrecognized flag.

Answer (score 0):

Below configuration worked for me

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <failOnError>false</failOnError>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```