# Trouble building apache mesos with jdk 1.8.0

Tags: java-8, mesos

I am new to apache mesos, while installing with JDK 1.8.0 receive the following error

```
    “[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [INFO] Total time: 03:21 min
     [INFO] Finished at: 2014-07-22T21:27:56+05:30
     [INFO] Final Memory: 23M/78M
     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.8.1:jar (build-and-attach-javadocs) on project mesos: MavenReportException: Error while creating archive:
     [ERROR] Exit code: 1 - /vol1/mesos-0.19.0/build/../src/java/src/org/apache/mesos/Executor.java:41: error: reference not found
     [ERROR] * data to it's executors through the {@link ExecutorInfo#data}
     [ERROR] ^
     [ERROR] /vol1/mesos-0.19.0/build/../src/java/src/org/apache/mesos/Executor.java:73: error: reference not found
     [ERROR] * via {@link Scheduler#launchTasks}. Note that this task can be
     [ERROR] ^
     [ERROR] /vol1/mesos-0.19.0/build/../src/java/src/org/apache/mesos/Executor.java:81: warning - Tag @link: can't find launchTasks in org.apache.mesos.Scheduler
     [ERROR] /vol1/mesos-0.19.0/build/../src/java/src/org/apache/mesos/Executor.java:50: warning - Tag @link: can't find data in org.apache.mesos.Protos.ExecutorInfo
     [ERROR] /vol1/mesos-0.19.0/build/../src/java/src/org/apache/mesos/Log.java:251: warning: no @param for identity
     [ERROR] public Position position(byte[] identity) {
     [ERROR] ^
     [ERROR] /vol1/mesos-0.19.0/build/../src/java/src/org/apache/mesos/Log.java:251: warning: no @return
     [ERROR] public Position position(byte[] identity) {
     [ERROR] ^
     [ERROR] /vol1/mesos-0.19.0/build/../src/java/src/org/apache/mesos/Log.java:65: warning: no @return
     [ERROR] public byte[] identity() {
     [ERROR] ^
     [ERROR] /vol1/mesos-0.19.0/build/../src/java/src/org/apache/mesos/Log.java:149: warning: no @param for from
     [ERROR] public native List<Entry> read(Position from,
     [ERROR] ^
     [ERROR] /vol1/mesos-0.19.0/build/../src/java/src/org/apache/mesos/Log.java:149: warning: no @param for to
     [ERROR] public native List<Entry> read(Position from,
     [ERROR] ^
     [ERROR] /vol1/mesos-0.19.0/build/../src/java/src/org/apache/mesos/Log.java:149: warning: no @param for timeout
     [ERROR] public native List<Entry> read(Position from,
     [ERROR] ^
     [ERROR] /vol1/mesos-0.19.0/build/../src/java/src/org/apache/mesos/Log.java:149: warning: no @param for unit
     [ERROR] public native List<Entry> read(Position from,
     [ERROR] ^
     [ERROR] /vol1/mesos-0.19.0/build/../src/java/src/org/apache/mesos/Log.java:149: warning: no @return
     [ERROR] public native List<Entry> read(Position from,
     [ERROR] ^
     [ERROR] /vol1/mesos-0.19.0/build/../src/java/src/org/apache/mesos/Log.java:149: warning: no @throws for java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
     [ERROR] public native List<Entry> read(Position from,
     [ERROR] ^
     [ERROR] /vol1/mesos-0.19.0/build/../src/java/src/org/apache/mesos/Log.java:149: warning: no @throws for org.apache.mesos.Log.OperationFailedException
     [ERROR] public native List<Entry> read(Position from,
     [ERROR] ^
     [ERROR] /vol1/mesos-0.19.0/build/../src/java/src/org/apache/mesos/Log.java:159: warning: no @return
     [ERROR] public native Position beginning();
     [ERROR] ^
     [ERROR] /vol1/mesos-0.19.0/build/../src/java/src/org/apache/mesos/Log.java:165: warning: no @return
     [ERROR] public native Position ending();
     [ERROR] ^
     [ERROR] /vol1/mesos-0.19.0/build/../src/java/src/org/apache/mesos/Log.java:191: warning: no @param for data
     [ERROR] public native Position append(byte[] data, long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
     [ERROR] ^
     [ERROR] /vol1/mesos-0.19.0/build/../src/java/src/org/apache/mesos/Log.java:191: warning: no  @param for timeout
     [ERROR] public native Position append(byte[] data, long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
     [ERROR] ^
     [ERROR] /vol1/mesos-0.19.0/build/../src/java/src/org/apache/mesos/Log.java:191: warning: no @param for unit
     [ERROR] public native Position append(byte[] data, long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
     [ERROR] ^
     [ERROR] /vol1/mesos-0.19.0/build/../src/java/src/org/apache/mesos/Log.java:191: warning: no @return
     [ERROR] public native Position append(byte[] data, long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
     [ERROR] ^
     [ERROR] /vol1/mesos-0.19.0/build/../src/java/src/org/apache/mesos/Log.java:191: warning: no @throws for java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
     [ERROR] public native Position append(byte[] data, long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
     [ERROR] ^
     [ERROR] /vol1/mesos-0.19.0/build/../src/java/src/org/apache/mesos/Log.java:191: warning: no @throws for org.apache.mesos.Log.WriterFailedException
```

While running it with JDK 1.7 it works fine 
Is there anything I am missing to make it work with 1.8 or this is not currently supported ?

Any advice please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're missing javadoc annotations in `./src/java/mesos.pom.in`

[Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886209/maven-is-not-working-in-java-8-when-javadoc-tags-are-incomplete)

Comment: +1 for the link, seems like a blocker at this moment.