# JavaDoc will not publish on jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, javadoc, publish

I have an aggregator project built in jenkins and I want to publish javadocs. So I installed javadoc plugin and changed my parent pom as follows:

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.9.1</version>
<configuration>
      <aggregate>true</aggregate>
      <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/apidocs</outputDirectory>
 </configuration>
```

I tried different configurations but this is the only one that won't fail the build. With this configuration the build doesn't fail but no javadocs are to be found. Am I missing something here? Does anyone has the same problem?

Comment: Jenkins crashed for us due to Java 8's DocLint causing an error for self-closing tags such as `<p/>` and IntelliJ IDEA's auto-formatter auto-generated those. I don't know if this has anything to do with that, just figured I'd mention it.

Comment: To suppress the DocLint errors, set `<additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886209/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should use the `aggregate` goal instead of the parameter [cause it's marked deprecated](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/aggregate.html).

Furthermore you should configure javadoc plugin like the following in your root pom like this:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Default configuration for all reports -->
          ...
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>aggregate</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>aggregate</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
              <!-- Specific configuration for the aggregate report -->
              ...
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          ...
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Afterwards you should be able just by:

```
mvn clean package
```

This will result in a folder in the root `target/apidoc` which contains the created aggregated javadocs.

Comment: I ran maven with this javadoc configuration and still there is no apidoc folder. Now exists a folder in the root [target/site] and also [target/javadoc-bundle-options] but both don't contain any javadocs. Also the build fails due to OutOfMemory error, which didn't happened before. I am guessing it has somtheing to do with the javadoc plugin. Any idea what might have happened?

Comment: The OutOfMemory error can be handled simply by adding to the javadoc configurations <maxmemory>1024</maxmemory>. The problem that I still have is that I can't find any javadocs. Do you have any suggestions @khmarbaise?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to publish the javadocs as .jar. I used the above pom configuration with the small change:

```
<id>attach-javadocs</id>
<goals>
   <goal>jar</goal>
</goals>
```

It publishes javadocs as .jars for every sub-module. The javadocs are to be found in the sub-module directory not in the parent directory.