# wsimport generates &lt; instead of <

Tags: java-8, wsimport

Maybe this has been answered already but I'll ask anyway since I don't find an answer.

When running wsimport on a wsdl the Javadoc in the generated classes starts their lines with

```
&lt;
```

This doesn't work with jdk8 and maven.

The lines ends with a normal `>`

How can I make the lines start with a `<`?

Comment: Show an example. javadoc contains HTML, and < is a special character that must be escaped in HTML, so tht's expected and normal. javadoc is meant to be read in a web browser, not in the source code directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am quite sure that your diagnosis is reversed: the errors you get with Java 8 are about those "normal" `>` characters because the new, strict Javadoc rules state that you must escape both `<` and `>`. Refer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886209/maven-is-not-working-in-java-8-when-javadoc-tags-are-incomplete) for more details. There is a workaround which involves a flag to disable the strictness.

Comment: +1. I didn't quite understand the question. BTW, the linked answer disables **all** the lint checks. To only disable the html checks, the option should be `-Xdoclint:-html`.