# CMU Sphinx4 Unable to build project

Tags: java, maven, cmusphinx, sphinx4

While trying to build Sphinx4 Core project

[image]

I get errors/warnings

```
100 errors
100 warnings
MavenReportException: Error while creating archive: 
Exit code: 1 - C:\Users\Shivam Tiwari\Documents\NetBeansProjects\sphinx4\sphinx4-core\src\main\java\edu\cmu\sphinx\alignment\DecisionTree.java:43: error: bad use of '>'
 * <li>>- the feature is greater than the value
       ^
C:\Users\Shivam Tiwari\Documents\NetBeansProjects\sphinx4\sphinx4-

core\src\main\java\edu\cmu\sphinx\alignment\DecisionTree.java:53: error: bad use of '>'
     * For &lt; and >, this CART coerces the value and feature to float's. For =,
                    ^
.
.
.
Many more such errors
```

The pom.xml is

```
    <project
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
  http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>edu.cmu.sphinx</groupId>
    <artifactId>sphinx4-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>sphinx4-core</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Sphinx4 core</name>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
      <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>edu.cmu.sphinx</groupId>
      <artifactId>sphinx4-data</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>forplay-legacy</id>
      <url>http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</project>
```

The configuration I am using is

[image]

Is there anyone who can point out why I get these errors? Is there some dependency I am missing or is there some other build profile?

Answer (score 1):

The problem maybe that some of the Javadoc in the project does not meet the Javadoc standards.

Try Turning off doclint

For reference read this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16743137/2627215