# MVN Install failed

Tags: java, maven, mojo, mojo-sdk

I'm getting a MojoExecutionException, how do i solve this. I am trying to execute an open source project with maven, the project is [here](https://github.com/pyvandenbussche/lovScripts). In the repository, it says nodejs, mongodb and elasticsearch should be running, I ensured this

The error is:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building LOV Scripts 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) @ lovscripts ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 125 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ lovscripts ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 85 source files to /home/noor/lovScripts-master/target/classes
[WARNING] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/LovUtil.java: /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/LovUtil.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[WARNING] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/LovUtil.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ lovscripts ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ lovscripts ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ lovscripts ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/noor/lovScripts-master/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.2:jar (default-jar) @ lovscripts ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/noor/lovScripts-master/target/lovscripts.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (attach-sources) @ lovscripts >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (attach-sources) @ lovscripts <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (attach-sources) @ lovscripts ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/noor/lovScripts-master/target/lovscripts-sources.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:2.9:jar (attach-javadocs) @ lovscripts ---
[INFO] 
Loading source files for package org.lov.vocidex.describers...
Loading source files for package org.lov.vocidex...
Loading source files for package org.lov.vocidex.extract...
Loading source files for package org.lov...
Loading source files for package org.lov.rdf2mongo.describers...
Loading source files for package org.lov.rdf2mongo.iterators...
Loading source files for package org.lov.rdf2mongo.extractors...
Loading source files for package org.lov.rdf2mongo...
Loading source files for package org.lov.objects...
Loading source files for package org.lov.dif.describers...
Loading source files for package org.lov.cli...
Constructing Javadoc information...
Standard Doclet version 1.8.0_65
Building tree for all the packages and classes...
Generating /home/noor/lovScripts-master/target/apidocs/org/lov/vocidex/describers/AgentDescriber.html...
Generating /home/noor/lovScripts-master/target/apidocs/org/lov/vocidex
Generating /home/noor/lovScripts-master/target/apidocs/org/lov/objects/class-use/VocabularySuggest.html...
Generating /home/noor/lovScripts-master/target/apidocs/org/lov/objects
Generating /home/noor/lovScripts-master/target/apidocs/index.html...
Generating /home/noor/lovScripts-master/target/apidocs/overview-summary.html...
Generating /home/noor/lovScripts-master/target/apidocs/help-doc.html...
2 errors
36 warnings
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.186s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Oct 24 19:05:48 CEST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/318M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.9:jar (attach-javadocs) on project lovscripts: MavenReportException: Error while creating archive:
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/vocidex/JSONHelper.java:39: warning: no @param for fileName
[ERROR] public static String readFile(String fileName) {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/vocidex/JSONHelper.java:39: warning: no @return
[ERROR] public static String readFile(String fileName) {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/vocidex/describers/LabelDescriber.java:41: warning: no @param for uri
[ERROR] public String synthesizeLabelFromURI(String uri) {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/vocidex/describers/LabelDescriber.java:41: warning: no @return
[ERROR] public String synthesizeLabelFromURI(String uri) {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/vocidex/describers/StrLiteralDescriber.java:111: warning: no @param for uri
[ERROR] public String synthesizeLabelFromURI(String uri) {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/vocidex/describers/StrLiteralDescriber.java:111: warning: no @return
[ERROR] public String synthesizeLabelFromURI(String uri) {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/vocidex/VocidexIndex.java:86: warning: no @param for document
[ERROR] public String addDocument(VocidexDocument document) {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/vocidex/extract/AgentsExtractor.java:30: warning: no @return
[ERROR] public Iterator<VocidexDocument> persons() {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/vocidex/extract/AgentsExtractor.java:37: warning: no @return
[ERROR] public Iterator<VocidexDocument> organizations() {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/vocidex/extract/AgentsExtractor.java:43: warning: no description for @return
[ERROR] * @return
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/vocidex/extract/LOVWrapper.java:34: warning: no @param for termMetricsDescriber
[ERROR] public LOVWrapper(VocabularyTermExtractor wrapped, Collection<Resource> eligibleResources, final ObjectNode vocabularyDescription, final LOVTermMetricsDescriber termMetricsDescriber) {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/vocidex/extract/VocabularyTermExtractor.java:41: warning: no @return
[ERROR] public Iterator<VocidexDocument> classes() {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/vocidex/extract/VocabularyTermExtractor.java:48: warning: no @return
[ERROR] public Iterator<VocidexDocument> properties() {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/vocidex/extract/VocabularyTermExtractor.java:55: warning: no @return
[ERROR] public Iterator<VocidexDocument> datatypes() {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/vocidex/extract/VocabularyTermExtractor.java:62: warning: no @return
[ERROR] public Iterator<VocidexDocument> instances() {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/vocidex/extract/VocabularyTermExtractor.java:32: warning: no @param for tag
[ERROR] public VocabularyTermExtractor(SPARQLRunner source, String prefix, String tag) {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/LovBotVocabAnalyser.java:38: warning: no @param for vocabularyversionURL
[ERROR] public static VocabularySuggest analyseVersion(String vocabularyversionURL, String vocabularyURI, String vocabularyNsp, Lang lang, Properties lovConfig) throws Exception{
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/LovBotVocabAnalyser.java:38: warning: no @param for vocabularyURI
[ERROR] public static VocabularySuggest analyseVersion(String vocabularyversionURL, String vocabularyURI, String vocabularyNsp, Lang lang, Properties lovConfig) throws Exception{
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/LovBotVocabAnalyser.java:38: warning: no @param for vocabularyNsp
[ERROR] public static VocabularySuggest analyseVersion(String vocabularyversionURL, String vocabularyURI, String vocabularyNsp, Lang lang, Properties lovConfig) throws Exception{
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/LovBotVocabAnalyser.java:38: warning: no @param for lang
[ERROR] public static VocabularySuggest analyseVersion(String vocabularyversionURL, String vocabularyURI, String vocabularyNsp, Lang lang, Properties lovConfig) throws Exception{
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/LovBotVocabAnalyser.java:38: warning: no @param for lovConfig
[ERROR] public static VocabularySuggest analyseVersion(String vocabularyversionURL, String vocabularyURI, String vocabularyNsp, Lang lang, Properties lovConfig) throws Exception{
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/LovBotVocabAnalyser.java:38: warning: no @return
[ERROR] public static VocabularySuggest analyseVersion(String vocabularyversionURL, String vocabularyURI, String vocabularyNsp, Lang lang, Properties lovConfig) throws Exception{
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/LovBotVocabAnalyser.java:38: warning: no @throws for java.lang.Exception
[ERROR] public static VocabularySuggest analyseVersion(String vocabularyversionURL, String vocabularyURI, String vocabularyNsp, Lang lang, Properties lovConfig) throws Exception{
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/LovBotVocabAnalyser.java:46: warning: no @param for vocabularyURI
[ERROR] public static VocabularySuggest analyseVocabURI(String vocabularyURI, Properties lovConfig) throws Exception{
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/LovBotVocabAnalyser.java:46: warning: no @param for lovConfig
[ERROR] public static VocabularySuggest analyseVocabURI(String vocabularyURI, Properties lovConfig) throws Exception{
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/LovBotVocabAnalyser.java:46: warning: no @return
[ERROR] public static VocabularySuggest analyseVocabURI(String vocabularyURI, Properties lovConfig) throws Exception{
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/LovBotVocabAnalyser.java:46: warning: no @throws for java.lang.Exception
[ERROR] public static VocabularySuggest analyseVocabURI(String vocabularyURI, Properties lovConfig) throws Exception{
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/StatementHelper.java:23: warning: no description for @param
[ERROR] * @param resourceSubject
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/StatementHelper.java:24: warning: no description for @param
[ERROR] * @param property
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/StatementHelper.java:25: warning: no description for @param
[ERROR] * @param literalValue
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/StatementHelper.java:27: warning: no description for @param
[ERROR] * @param lang
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/rdf2mongo/iterators/AgentsDescriberIterator.java:14: error: reference not found
[ERROR] * {@link Vocabulary}s by calling a {@link Describer}
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/rdf2mongo/iterators/UsersDescriberIterator.java:13: error: reference not found
[ERROR] * {@link User}s by calling a {@link Describer}
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/rdf2mongo/extractors/AgentsExtractor.java:31: warning: no @return
[ERROR] public Iterator<Agent> persons() {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/rdf2mongo/extractors/AgentsExtractor.java:38: warning: no @return
[ERROR] public Iterator<Agent> organizations() {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/rdf2mongo/extractors/AgentsExtractor.java:45: warning: no @return
[ERROR] public Iterator<Agent> swAgents() {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/rdf2mongo/extractors/LanguagesExtractor.java:28: warning: no @return
[ERROR] public Iterator<Language> getLanguages() {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home/noor/lovScripts-master/src/main/java/org/lov/rdf2mongo/extractors/UsersExtractor.java:31: warning: no @return
[ERROR] public Iterator<User> getcurators() {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Command line was: /home/noor/Applications/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/../bin/javadoc @options @packages
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Refer to the generated Javadoc files in '/home/noor/lovScripts-master/target/apidocs' dir.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Might be a dupe. Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886209/maven-is-not-working-in-java-8-when-javadoc-tags-are-incomplete

Comment: Yes, I think this is the problem. You should build this project with Java 7: the `pom.xml` defines a 1.7 source and target. It is not enforced but it should be.