# Java 8 javadoc doclint feature 'tag not allowed here'

Tags: java, javadoc

I have recently upgraded my project from Java 7 to 8. I have stumbled upon a number of error because of doclint feature for javadoc.
error: tag not allowed here:

HTML Tag in java file:

```html
<a name="ThpSslEnabled"></a>
```

I tried checking for conformance with W3C HTML standards for anchor tag, but did not find anything which could be helpful.

Comment: Could you paste the complete javadoc block that contains the error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you using Maven or any other build software?

DocLint is enabled by default in Java 8, and will run a whole lot of checks before generating Javadocs. You need to turn this off for Java 8.

Check this answer:
[Maven is not working in Java 8 when JavaDoc tags are incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886209/maven-is-not-working-in-java-8-when-javadoc-tags-are-incomplete)

```
<properties>
    <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
</properties>
```

Comment: I am using gradle and currently I am suppressing the error by turning off doclint but want to fix the error.

Comment: How to turn it off in gradle?