# How to compile ELKI project with Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, elki

I have been working on this issue since yesterday.

The latest ELKI has a glitch and the developer fixed it on GitHub.

However, I have to re-compile the project to use it.

I have installed latest Java JDK and Maven. However, the build command always terminates with an error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.application.internal.DocumentParameters
```

This is the project: https://github.com/elki-project/elki.

I am running this command:

```
mvn -DskipTests -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -P svg,bundle package
```

I have sent numerous e-mails to the developer and he said he doesn't have time to help me.

I believe that the package has errors rather than I am doing error.

So you can you test and let me know how to build it?

I'm using Windows 8.1 x64.

I even tried with Eclipse and it gives errors, too:

[image]

Comment: What if you build [`elki-bundle`](https://github.com/elki-project/elki/blob/master/addons/bundle/pom.xml) alone? Does it build successfully?

Comment: @geroldbroser I don't know how to do that.  By the way I did a fresh Ubuntu install and same command worked .  I guess it doesn't work on Windows

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we don't test with Windows much; and the **single-jar option is mostly for releases**, so it does not get a whole lot of attention. We built on Linux, and as you noticed it worked there for you, too.

We have recently seen some issues pop up with Eclipse, Maven and M2E integration. Our documentation builders (including `DocumentParameters`) need to do introspection of all classes, so they need to run quite late in the build process; but Maven (in particular with Eclipse) only supports the default build lifecycle reliably. The git repository contains another workaround that may help. But usually if you fix build on one system/environment, it breaks on another, unfortunately.