# Maven error: -fuzzyMatcher TYPEVAR

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.3:jar (package-javadocs) on project globalmentor-core: MavenReportException: Error while generating Javadoc:
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - fuzzyMatcher TYPEVAR
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Command line was: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\..\bin\javadoc.exe" @options @packages
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Refer to the generated Javadoc files in 'C:\Users\magno\Documents\Globalmentor\globalmentor-core\target\apidocs' dir.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.3:jar (package-javadocs) on project globalmentor-core: MavenReportException: Error while generating Javadoc:
Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - fuzzyMatcher TYPEVAR

Command line was: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\..\bin\javadoc.exe" @options @packages

Refer to the generated Javadoc files in 'C:\Users\magno\Documents\Globalmentor\globalmentor-core\target\apidocs' dir.

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: MavenReportException: Error while generating Javadoc:
Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - fuzzyMatcher TYPEVAR

Command line was: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\..\bin\javadoc.exe" @options @packages

Refer to the generated Javadoc files in 'C:\Users\magno\Documents\Globalmentor\globalmentor-core\target\apidocs' dir.

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.failOnError(AbstractJavadocMojo.java:6018)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.JavadocJar.execute(JavadocJar.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.reporting.MavenReportException:
Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - fuzzyMatcher TYPEVAR

Command line was: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\..\bin\javadoc.exe" @options @packages

Refer to the generated Javadoc files in 'C:\Users\magno\Documents\Globalmentor\globalmentor-core\target\apidocs' dir.

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.executeJavadocCommandLine(AbstractJavadocMojo.java:5163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.executeReport(AbstractJavadocMojo.java:2075)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.JavadocJar.execute(JavadocJar.java:188)
    ... 22 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Can anybody help me to solve this error? I had some problems on javadocs and for a while it was used this additional lines on POM to solve this problem:

```
<!-- turn off Javadoc errors from warnings; requires JDK 8 -->
<additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
```

And now the problem is that it was needed to fix all the javadoc errors to make this library ready to be uploaded to maven, all the javadoc errors were fixed, but this problem persists. Any solution for this? I can't find this kind of error anywhere.

Here's the POM to see if anyone can help me to find the error that's probably here as many comments refer to this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.globalmentor</groupId>
<artifactId>globalmentor-core</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>GlobalMentor Core</name>
<url>http://www.globalmentor.com/</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/javascript</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>release</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-sources</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.10.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <bottom><![CDATA[<em>Copyright © 1996-2012 GlobalMentor, Inc. All Rights Reserved.</em>]]></bottom>
                        <quiet>true</quiet>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>package-javadocs</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:all</additionalparam>
                                <useStandardDocletOptions>false</useStandardDocletOptions>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And here's the versions of Maven and JVM I'm using:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T14:41:47-02:00)
Java version: 1.8.0_92, vendor: Oracle Corporation
```

Comment: I'd be interested to know if it gives more information if you run Maven using the `-e` switch as the error message suggested.

Comment: There it is @GarretWilson I added a more detailed version of the error so then you may see if you can help me with it.

Comment: Swap your `<additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>` </br> for </br>
`<additionalparam>-Xdoclint:all</additionalparam>` to see exactly where the problem is with your javadoc.

Comment: It gives me exactly the same error.

I wasn't using `<additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>` when I posted this error, it was used before because of the javadoc errors but when I started to fix them I needed to delete this line from POM. 

And If I use `<additionalparam>-Xdoclint:all</additionalparam>` or don't use anything I just receive the same error.

Comment: This is quite interesting. It appears that [this piece of javac(?) code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/com/sun/tools/javac/api/JavacTrees.java#JavacTrees) is throwing this error: `throw new AssertionError("fuzzyMatcher " + t.getTag());` With `t.getTag()` returning [`TYPEVAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/TypeKind.html#TYPEVAR). It's very strange that javadoc is doing this. This matches `- fuzzyMatcher TYPEVAR` in the actual error message you get, where `-` is part of the log message format.

Comment: My guess is javadoc encounters some piece of code that it considers illegal/impossible. Perhaps you can try figuring out what code it is by running javadoc with `-verbose` option. Do you use some source-processing libraries or other JVM-based languages, besides Java?

Comment: Can you include empty interfaces of one class that uses javadocs which can be used to reproduce the error?

Comment: The Maven code throwing this error can be found [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/2.10.3/org/apache/maven/plugin/javadoc/AbstractJavadocMojo.java#5163)... it's just reporting the error it got by calling the javadoc executable, so I would say it has nothing to do with your pom... Better would be if you could narrow down which javadoc is causing the issue, which file. If you have new javadocs written, it should be easy to figure out which one started causing this... otherwise, just remove stuff until it works.

Comment: Once you found out which java file is causing this, please post it in your question as that'll be the important thing to know.

Comment: I'm working on the file to see if I can find anything, if I do I'll post here what was going on to help future cases about this error. If not, I'll see if I'm authorized to post the class here as I don't own the copyright about the project. Thank you everybody, I'll get back to this as soon as I can.

Answer (score -1):

### UPDATE:

### Oracle Declaration: [Doclint, a new feature of Java 8.](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/172)

> The `javax.tools` package contains classes and interfaces that enable
>   you to invoke the Javadoc tool directly from a Java application,
>   without executing a new process. The [javadoc tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/whatsnew-8.html) now has support for
>   checking the content of javadoc comments for issues that could lead to
>   various problems, such as invalid HTML or accessibility issues, in the
>   files that are generated by javadoc. The feature is enabled by
>   default, and can also be controlled by the new `-Xdoclint` option.

---

But there are **some issues and errors occurred** when we want to implement in our coding.

### From [Stephen Colebourne's blog](http://blog.joda.org/2014/02/turning-off-doclint-in-jdk-8-javadoc.html), we got that

**Up to JDK 7**, the Javadoc tool was pretty lenient. As a developer, you could write anything that vaguely resembled HTML and the tool would rarely complain beyond warnings. Thus you could have `@link` references that were inaccurate (such as due to refactoring) and the tool would simply provide a warning.

**With JDK 8**, you are unable to get Javadoc unless your tool meets the standards of doclint. Some of its rules are:

1. no self-closed HTML tags, such as `<br />` or `<a id="x" />`
2. no unclosed HTML tags, such as `<ul>` without matching `</ul>`
3. no invalid HTML end tags, such as `</br>`
4. no invalid HTML attributes, based on doclint's interpretation of W3C
   HTML 4.01
5. no duplicate HTML id attribute
6. no empty HTML href attribute
7. no incorrectly nested headers, such as class documentation must have
   `<h3>`, not `<h4>`
8. no invalid HTML tags, such as `List<String>` (where you forgot to
   escape using `&lt;`)
9. no broken `@link` references
10. no broken `@param` references, they must match the actual parameter
     name
11. no broken `@throws` references, the first word must be a class name

**Note that these are errors, not warnings. Break the rules and you get no Javadoc output.**

### Solution:

In a single word, if we want to give solution, then you have to make -`Xdoclint:none`.

An example is given in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886209/maven-is-not-working-in-java-8-when-javadoc-tags-are-incomplete/26806103#26806103):

But if you want to make it runnable, then you must have overcome above criteria of JDK 8.

### [When this problem will be fixed by Oracle?](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/212)

We may have to wait until `Java 9.`

### Resource Link:

1. [Maven is not working in Java 8 when JavaDoc tags are incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886209/maven-is-not-working-in-java-8-when-javadoc-tags-are-incomplete)

---

`<useStandardDocletOptions>` MUST be set to `false` once  is specified. Make `useStandardDocletOptions` to `false` and use this line afer `additionalparam` as given below.

```
<additionalparam>-Xdoclint:all</additionalparam>
<useStandardDocletOptions>false</useStandardDocletOptions>
```

### Resource Link:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAVADOC-229

Comment: I'm using Java 8 now

Comment: @MagnoNascimento I have updated my answer. Would you please check and let me know.

Comment: Changing the version of Java on POM still didn't help me... same error.

Comment: @SkyWalker, where exactly in your answer did you mention the specific error `-fuzzyMatcher TYPEVAR`? It's one thing to copy and paste a lot of information from somebody else's blog entry (most information of which we already knew), but I put up 100 points in order to find an answer to this specific question. If you could directly answer the question it would be much appreciated.

Comment: @SkyWalker, _"And now the problem is that it was needed to fix all the javadoc errors to make this library ready to be uploaded to maven, all the javadoc errors were fixed, but this problem persists. Any solution for this? I can't find this kind of error anywhere."_ with this _"all the javadoc errors"_ I meant what you said on the last update, all those items from 1 to 11. The answer is starting to get away of the point we want to come. I appreciate your help, but we really need to fix this.

Comment: @MagnoNascimento Actually all the javadoc errors are need to be fixed. As you are saying but I think you have missed something. For this reason, it is not fixed. If possible, you can share your project through github. Then I will make a try.