# How to disable Javadoc warnings in Maven Javadoc Plugin?

Tags: maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I'm using the Maven Javadoc Plugin. It outputs warnings as follows:

```
[ERROR] /home/monperrus/spoon/src/main/java/spoon/visitor/CtVisitor.java:144:
      warning: no @param for <T>
```

How to not display those warnings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven is not working in Java 8 when Javadoc tags are incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886209/maven-is-not-working-in-java-8-when-javadoc-tags-are-incomplete)

Comment: Remember to accept an answer if it was helpful @Martin.

Answer (score 28):

Since version 3.0.0 of the `maven-javadoc-plugin` you can use the `doclint` configuration parameter. If you just want to disable the "missing" warnings, use `all,-missing`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <doclint>all,-missing</doclint>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

For more information see [the `doclint` parameter documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/jar-mojo.html#doclint).

Answer (score 23):

> How to display those warnings as [WARNING] (and not the confusing [ERROR])? How to completely disable Javadoc warnings in Maven?

If you are talking about the javadoc lint warnings introduced in Java 8 then you should be able to do the following.  There are multiple ways of specifying the parameters depending on which version of the javadoc plugin you are using.

```
<plugins>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
         <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
         <additionalOptions>-Xdoclint:none</additionalOptions>
         <additionalJOption>-Xdoclint:none</additionalJOption>
      </configuration>
   </plugin>
</plugins>
```

See this [good discussion about turning off doclint](http://blog.joda.org/2014/02/turning-off-doclint-in-jdk-8-javadoc.html).

If you are instead just want to get rid of the missing jacadocs warnings then you can use:

```
<configuration>
   <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:all -Xdoclint:-missing</additionalparam>
   <additionalOptions>-Xdoclint:all -Xdoclint:-missing</additionalOptions>
   <additionalJOptions>
     <additionalJOption>-Xdoclint:all</additionalJOption>
     <additionalJOption>-Xdoclint:-missing</additionalJOption>
   </additionalJOptions>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 20):

maven-javadoc-plugin version 2.9 onwards, setting additionalparam, doesn't seem to work. The new option that needs to be set is additionalJOption (see [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html)). An example here:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <additionalJOption>-Xdoclint:none</additionalJOption>
        </configuration>
   </plugin>
```

Note that the warning are still displayed in the console, but not with the confusing "[ERROR]" prefix.

Note also, per the code of `maven-javadoc-plugin` that if there is at least one Javadoc error, all log lines will be prefixed by `[ERROR]`.

Answer (score 13):

You can also disable it from the command line, in case you just want to locally suppress but not codify.

```
mvn clean install -Dadditionalparam=-Xdoclint:none
```

as Spring Monkey points out, in newer versions you may have to pass it in as

```
mvn clean install -DadditionalJOption=-Xdoclint:none
```

Comment: Passing `-DadditionalJOption=-Xdoclint:none` option to `mvn` worked for me.

Comment: You can also add `-Ddoclint=none` to the `mvn` command line https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/aggregate-mojo.html#doclint

Answer (score 8):

From v3.0.0, new [`doclint`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#doclint) config option is added to configure the doc linting. This can be used to suppress these warnings.

```xml
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <doclint>none</doclint>  <!-- Turnoff all checks -->
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

For < v3.0.0, use as mentioned in previous answers

```xml
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>  <!-- Turnoff all checks -->
    </configuration>
    <!-- executions.... -->
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 2):

Compiling all the answers, and adding something else, we have the following.

*To configure the maven project* you should add this to the pom file:

```
<plugins>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
         <additionalJOption>-Xdoclint:none</additionalJOption>
      </configuration>
   </plugin>
</plugins>
```

For Maven 2.9+ you need `additionalJOption`, and before that you need `additionalparam`. You can have `additionalparam` on Maven 2.9+ as it won't cause errors, but it won't make it work. I have not tested having `additionalJOption` on earlier versions of maven.

*To configure it from the command line*, you should pass this parameter:

```
mvn <goals> -Dadditionalparam=-Xdoclint:none -DadditionalJOption=-Xdoclint:none
```

*To configure it on your shell environment*, so that it will apply every time to every project without you needing to do anything else, add this line to your shell initialization (`~/.bashrc` or on Macs `~/.bash_profile`, or whatever else your shell uses):

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dadditionalparam=-Xdoclint:none -DadditionalJOption=-Xdoclint:none"
```

Or, if you have a `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`, append those parameters to it.

Answer (score 0):

The [maven plugin page](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#failOnError) shows how you can disable them_

```
<failOnWarnings>
<failOnError>
```

The default for warnings is false, so it won't break the build. The default for errors is (of course) true.