# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

When I build the project with dependencies, it gives this error.

`Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.4:jar (attach-javadocs) on project appointmentscheduling-api: MavenReportException: Error while generating Javadoc:`

Previously I could build it properly. I didn't change anything, I tried a backup sample as well. But this error come always. Tried re-installing javadoc plugin. There are some answers which says to change the pom.xml file. They didn't work for me either. Somebody help me to solve this please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Run maven in debug mode (-X) , which will give you more clarity about the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you upgraded to JDK8 lately? You might be running into [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886209/maven-is-not-working-in-java-8-when-javadoc-tags-are-incomplete). The solution would be one of:

- Launch Maven with JDK < 8
- Apply workaround from link above

Comment: That was the issue. Downgraded java to 7. Now it's working well. Thanks. But still I'm confused about being able to build it properly previously. 