# Site reports are missing after Javadoc configuration

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-site-plugin, maven-javadoc-plugin

I followed the advice of https://stackoverflow.com/a/16743137/927493 to deactivate the doclint check for sites, putting

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <reportPlugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <additionalparam>${javadoc.opts}</additionalparam>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </reportPlugins>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

into the build section, where `javadoc.opts` is `-Xdoclint:none`.

This works, but unfortunately, the site now only contains the javadoc report, no other reports.

Until now, I had no configuration for site reports, but my tries to add a `<reporting>` section were in vain. I tried to add

```
<reporting>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
    <reportSets>
      <reportSet>
        <reports>
          <report>dependencies</report>
          <report>project-team</report>
          <report>mailing-list</report>
          <report>cim</report>
          <report>issue-tracking</report>
          <report>license</report>
          <report>scm</report>
        </reports>
      </reportSet>
    </reportSets>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</reporting>
```

but none of the reports are generated.

Summarized: I want to generate a standard set of reports in the site while deactivating doclint for javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the configuration

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <additionalparam>${javadoc.opts}</additionalparam>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

from the `<reportPlugins>` section to the `<reporting>` section did the trick. Actually, I don't know why, and I do not know the purpose of the ´` section.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in moving the plugin into the `<reporting>` section of the pom.xml.

Another thing to note is that if you want to disable doclint in a different way, you can set a property in the pom xml as follows

```
<properties>
    <doclint>none</doclint>
</properties>
```

This will disable doclint rather than needing to specify multiple tags within the plugin

https://dkbalachandar.wordpress.com/2017/12/20/turn-off-doclint-in-jdk-8/